# Apache rewrite rule undesirably applies for different directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

**The Setup**

My setup is to have resources shared for two or more sites that have similar structures though different content. In example...

```
http:// localhost/site1/
http:// localhost/site2/
```

The rewrite rules are intended to add exceptions for the shared resources. In example the scripts folder (and of course everything inside of it) is rewritten so...

```
http:// localhost/scripts/
```

...is accessible at...

```
http:// localhost/site1/scripts/
http:// localhost/site2/scripts/
```

**The Problem**

When trying to access...

```
http:// localhost/site1/scripts/admin.js
```

...the following rewrite applies via the current rule and tries to rewrite it to the admin directory...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*/admin(.+) admin$1 [QSA] #Messes with scripts/admin.js
```

I think this is a directory depth issue, where the rule .*/ can apply to more than the first directory (site1/) and also inherently (and undesirably) applies to all directory depths (e.g. depth1/depth2/depth3/ etc).

**Desired Outcome**

How do I adjust this rule so that...

1. The admin index (site1/admin/) is caputed by this rule.
2. The admin JavaScript file (site1/scripts/admin.js) is ignored by this rule.
3. We keep the dynamic starting bit of the rule (RewriteRule .*/admin) so no matter the name of the directory that is used Apache will continue to automatically just work *or* we can modify it to have the same effect but the end result is that it must remain dynamic.
4. I do not rename admin.js as it would be cheap and thus I won't learn from this.

Comment: I've read this question through, and I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please give some examples of things that should be rewritten (and what they should become) and things that shouldn't be rewritten.

Comment: localhost/site1/example.js is rewritten to localhost/scripts/example.js (correctly)

Comment: localhost/site1/admin.js is captured by the rule in the post and is throws an HTTP 404. I think because .*/ may apply to TWO directory depth instead of ONLY one directory depth. Can we LIMIT the directory depth of the rule then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you can try depending on how you have everything else working. If the *site1/scripts/admin.js* exists and you want to have URI's that access existing files (like scripts, or images) not to be rewritten, you can try adding this right before the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Or, you can also just make it so scripts won't get rewritten by adding this right before the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$
```

Requests that end with **.js** will fail that condition and the rule will not be applied. Alternatively, you can narrow it down specifically to `admin\.js` or `scripts/[^\.]+\.js` (replacing the `\.js` in the condition).

---

> Can we LIMIT the directory depth of the rule then?

You can if you use `[^/]+` instead of `.*`.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$ worked, thank you. I am still open to a directory depth limit if you or anyone else wants to contribute; the more working code we have the more likely this will help others as well.